# Will a script added with insertBefore (async=false) loaded next?

Tags: javascript

Let's asume I put this script directly after the starting head-tag:

```
(function () {
     var a = document.createElement('script');
     var m = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     a.async = !1;
     a.src = 'loader.js';
     m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
 })();
```

Can I be sure, that the loader.js will be executed right after the above function block?

Although the loading of the loader.js is inserted before the current position the browser is executing.

Comment: Why not just read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)?

Comment: It's **inserted** when that code runs, no sooner or no later. Most browsers will however **execute** inserted script tags as async by default, meaning the script will be executed when the thread is free, whenever that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Browser_compatibility):

> Script-inserted scripts execute asynchronously in IE and WebKit, but
>   synchronously in Opera and pre-4.0 Firefox. In Firefox 4.0, the async
>   DOM property defaults to true for script-created scripts, so the
>   default behavior matches the behavior of IE and WebKit. To request
>   script-inserted external scripts be executed in the insertion order in
>   browsers where the `document.createElement("script").async` evaluates to
>   `true` (such as Firefox 4.0), set `.async=false` on the scripts you want
>   to maintain order.

Comment: In my example I have async = false. So order should be maintained. But I don't understand if this means that the browser will go backwards in the script and run the new script element next. Because the insertion is before the current script.

Comment: What is this insertion order? Is it temporary or is it based on location in DOM?

Comment: It doesn't matter where is the insertion. The fact is that calling (parent) script is **already executed** at the moment of the inserted script creation, otherwise the inserted script couldn't be loaded.